# Any Smarty Users out there? Here's a domPDF challenge

Tags: templates, smarty, dompdf

I have a working dynamic content query/echo file that I need to convert to template for use with domPDF. Would someone look at my code that's not executing to see where I'm going wrong?

(Btw, the sendPDF.tpl file is in path: /Smarty/mg/templates/ -- sendPDF.php is in /Smarty/mg/ and smartyTEST.php is in my root path)

```
*****sendPDF.php********
<?php
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
session_start();
$art_id=$_SESSION['art_id'];

require '../libs/Smarty.class.php';


$message = "test page here";
$path0 = "artWorkImages/";
$path = "myGallerist/artWorkImages/";

foreach ($art_id as $art_id0){
//print_r("..id".$art_id0);
   $QUERY="SELECT * FROM artWork WHERE art_id = '$art_id0' ";
    $res = mysql_query($QUERY);
   $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
   if($num>0){

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
       $art_title = $row['art_title'];
       $art_id = $row['art_id'];
       $rep_email = $row['rep_email'];
       $make_avail = $row['make_avail'];
         $media = $row['media'];
         $height_in = $row['height_in'];
         $width_in = $row['width_in']; 
         $depth_in = $row['depth_in'];
         $height_cm = $row['height_cm'];
         $width_cm = $row['width_cm']; 
         $depth_cm = $row['depth_cm'];
         $art_year = $row['art_year'];      
       $about_art = $row['about_art'];
       $image_link = $row['image_link'];
           $location = $row['location'];
       $price = $row['price'];
       $curency = $row['curency'];
       $sale = $row['sale'];
       }
   }
}

$smarty->display('sendPDF.tpl');

?>

*******sendPDF.tpl*************
            <tr align="left" padding="3">
            <td align="left" width="80%" >
            <img src="slir/w500-h500/$path$image_link" ></a><br />
            $art_title, $media, $art_year<br />
            $height_in h x $width_in w x $depth_in d inches<br />
            $height_cm h x $width_cm w x $depth_cm d cm<br />

            Location: $location<br />
            Price: $price $curency<br />
            Sales/Contact email: $rep_email</td>
        <td align="left" width="20%"></td>
</tr>

**********smartyTEST.php*****************

<?php
///     Connect to database
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
//include the dom pdf
require('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

//fetch the HTML output from smarty template
$htmlcontent=$smarty->fetch('sendPDF.tpl');

//call dom pdf class
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($htmlcontent);
$dompdf->render();
//display output in browser
$dompdf->stream(110272009.pdf);
//or, save as a pdf
///$pdf = $dompdf->output();
///file_put_contents("tmp/filename.pdf", $pdf);

?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working? What error messages do you get? What is basic debugging telling you about the source of the problem - does the database work, for example?

Comment: a simple example of how Smarty would work with a "while" statement enclosed by a "foreach" would do. Thanks Allen

Comment: This routine works fine with code integrated with presentation (echo). I get nothing when I use smarty template separate from code. (btw, I'm new to Smarty)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing you doing any smarty assigns?
For instance, you have a PHP variable here:

```
 $media = $row['media'];
```

But that will not get to your smarty .tpl unless you do something like this:

```
$smarty->assign("media",$media);
```